# how can i setup firebase signalling server?

Tags: json, webrtc

I need to know the usage of firebase in Webrtc signalling and
how can I setup Firebase signalling server and how it is used in WebRTC 
can you please  provide me where to start
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I forked this project created by the Firebase team over two years ago (I'm not sure why Firebase deleted the original repository).  It covers all the webRTC basics, except you'll want to eventually use a TURN service like XirSys when you want to talk between networks.

https://github.com/mikeg0/gupshup